# How to prevent awk from sorting the array?

Tags: arrays, sorting, awk, text-processing

I'm trying to extract those lines from `data` text-file:

```
first
second
third
fourth
fifth
sixth
```

based on their lines numbers pre-saved in `nums` text-file:

```
2
6
3
```

and I ended up by the following [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) solution but it gives me the lines which are sorted based on their line-numbers and not according to orders in `nums` file.

```
$ awk  'NR==FNR{lines[$0];next } FNR in lines' nums data
second
third
sixth
```

But what I want to achieve is below output:

```
second
sixth
third
```

So, is there any option for `awk` to prevent/disable it from sorting the array?

Comment: You are using `FNR` in your second pattern. You are going to get your output in numerical order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handle the files the other way around:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { line[NR] = $0; next } { print line[$1] }' data nums
```